# Full code paths in clang errors

Tags: c++, c, clang

I am looking for the clang equivalent of the cl command /FC. I need full paths for my build tool to parse out and open the code files with the errors.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/027c4t2s.aspx

Comment: "cl"? How is that related to **c**ommon **l**isp?

Comment: Presumably `cl` is a visual studio thing.

Comment: Yes cl is the compiler that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: my study of the clang compiler parameters indicates there is no such facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a fully-qualified or relative path to the file on the command-line instead of only passing in the filename.  In the following example the debugger won't know where to find "blah.cc" because I compiled by specifying only the filename:

```
~ pwd
/mnt/scratch/myproject/src
~ clang++ blah.cc -c -o /mnt/scratch/myproject/build/blah.o
~ cd ../build
~ clang++ *.o -o myprogram
```

... however, if instead I'd done this:

```
~ pwd
/mnt/scratch/myproject
~ clang++ /mnt/scratch/myproject/src/blah.cc -c -o /mnt/scratch/myproject/build/blah.o
# or:
~ clang++ src/blah.cc -c -o build/blah.o
# ...
```

... then it embeds the fully-qualified or relative path into the debug sections.

If you use a partially qualified path, you'll have to tell GDB where to look for the code.  You can look at the documentation for it [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html), though two gdb commands that may be helpful:

```
# This will cause gdb to look in "path2" instead of "path1"
(gdb) set substitute-path path1 path2
# This allows you to give a list of directories to search for your source.
# note that if you give relative paths on the command-line, it'll concatenate
# these paths and the relative path used at compile-time.
(gdb) set directories path [path ...]
```

Comment: I see. So my solution to this is to get the working directory and add it onto my source files.

EDIT: Accidentally hit enter before I figured out the code tags.

SRCDIR=$(pwd)
SRCFILE="$SRCDIR/src/Testing.cc"
cd build
clang -g $SRCFILE -o Testing
cd ..

Answer (score 7):

CFLAGS+= -fdiagnostics-absolute-paths